# Kill a java process (in linux) by process name instead of PID

Tags: linux, process, pid

While configuring/installing Hadoop cluster we often need to kill a Java Process/Daemon.
We see Java Processes/Daemons running with `jps` command. 
Usually we kill a Java process with its PID. E.g.

```
kill -9 112224
```

It is little bit difficult to type the PID. Is there a way to kill the process by its name? In a single command?

Comment: pkill -f name assuming you have pkill installed.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here is the command to kill the Java process by is Process Name instead of its ProcessID.

```
kill -9 `jps | grep "DataNode" | cut -d " " -f 1`
```

Let me explain more, about the benefit of this command. Lets say you are working with Hadoop cluster. Its often required that you check java daemons running with `jps` command. Lets say when you give this command on worker nodes, you see following output.

```
1915 NodeManager
18119 DataNode
17680 Jps
```

Usually, if we want to kill DataNode process, we would use following command

```
kill -9 18119
```

But, it is little bit difficult to type the `PID`, to use `kill` command. By using the command, given in this answer, it is easy to write the name of the process. We can also prepare shell scripts to kill commonly used deamons in hadoop cluster,
or we can prepare one shell script and can use parameter as process name.

Comment: If you already know the answer then what's the point in posting it as question? shouldn't you delete the post?

Comment: Hi Rahul, 
My purpose was to share this solution, which can be used to kill Java Process which can't be killed wih pkill or killall commands.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for sharing this command, I used it to kill the jps "Server" processes. ie: kill `jps|grep "Server" | cut -d " " -f 1`, there are multiple server processes running and this command does kills all the processes but it takes a while.

Comment: kill `jps | ag "GenericTopology" | cut -d " " -f 1`, just install ag @ https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher

Answer (score 0):

How about using

```
killall firefox
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that what  meant was Java Processes running in Linux, which can be viewed with JPS command.
These Processes can't be killed with killall command.

Answer (score 0):

jps -l has helped me killing the process

```
kill `jps -l | grep "myjarname.jar" | cut -d " " -f 1`
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the process id of that java process run

**netstat -tuplen**

Process ID (PID) of that process whom you want to kill and run

**kill -9 PID**